# Magento category link to 404 error

Tags: php, magento, url-rewriting, magento-1.7

this is my first Magento project and I've run into such a big issue.
The Magento version I'm using is 1.7.0.2
I managed to create a custom left bar navigation bar using the following code in my "app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/navigation/category.phtml"

```
<?php
$cats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(1)->getChildren();
$catIds = explode(',',$cats);
?>
<div id="LeftCategory">
    <h2>Wicked Categories</h2>
    <hr style="color:white; height:1px; margin:5px;" />
<ul>
<?php foreach($catIds as $catId): ?>
    <li class="Li-Top-Category">
        <?php
            $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId);
            ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl()?>">
    <?php echo $category->getName()?>
</a>
<?php

            $subCats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId())->getChildren();
            $subCatIds = explode(',',$subCats);
        ?>
            <?php if(count($subCatIds) > 1):?>
                <ul>
                <?php foreach($subCatIds as $subCat) :?>
                    <li class="Li-Sub-Category">
                    <?php
                        $subCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCat);
            ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $subCategory->getUrl()?>">
    <?php echo $subCategory->getName()?>
</a>
<?php

                    ?>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach;?>
                </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>

</div>
```

It does the work to generate the category navigation. But the issue is, the URL each link points to doesn't work. All links are invalid that lead to the 404 Error Page.
You can see it here: http://wicked-shop.dev.thejinstudio.com/shop/catalog/category/view/s/accessories/id/15/

I've done so much search and nothing really solved this issue.
I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Seems you have created all these categories as "Root category". Root category doesn't have the URL key to browse. You need to change these categories to Subcategories of "Root category".

Comment: @PrasathAlbert Thank you for the point. How do I change "Root Category" to "Sub-category"? I don't see an option in Category Manager page.. Again, my version is 1.7.0.2

Comment: @PrasathAlbert I made it. Just drag and drop. The system will just work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `catalog/category` helper to get the proper URL from a category model

```
$_catalogCatgoryHelper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
```

Then with that helper pass your category to the `getCategoryUrl()` function

```
$_catalogCatgoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($category);
```

So give this a try. I've put my suggestions into your code:

```
<?php
$_catalogCatgoryHelper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
$cats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(1)->getChildren();
$catIds = explode(',',$cats);
?>
<div id="LeftCategory">
    <h2>Wicked Categories</h2>
    <hr style="color:white; height:1px; margin:5px;" />
<ul>
<?php foreach($catIds as $catId): ?>
    <li class="Li-Top-Category">
        <?php
            $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId);
            ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $_catalogCatgoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($category) ?>">
    <?php echo $category->getName()?>
</a>
<?php

            $subCats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId())->getChildren();
            $subCatIds = explode(',',$subCats);
        ?>
            <?php if(count($subCatIds) > 1):?>
                <ul>
                <?php foreach($subCatIds as $subCat) :?>
                    <li class="Li-Sub-Category">
                    <?php
                        $subCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCat);
            ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $_catalogCatgoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($subCategory)?>">
    <?php echo $subCategory->getName()?>
</a>
<?php

                    ?>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach;?>
                </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>

</div>
```

You might be better off with this code which I used in the past (but actually ended up rewriting so that it iteratively displays categories regardless of how deep they go, looking into how to do this would certainly be a good exercise for you). It is a bit cleaner, but you'll need to modify it slightly to your needs:

```
<?php $helper = $this->helper('catalog/category') ?>
<div class="block block-categorynavigation">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Category') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <?php $categories = $this->getStoreCategories() ?>
        <?php if (count($categories) > 0): ?>
            <ul id="leftnav-tree" class="level0">
                <?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
                    <li class="level0<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($category)): ?> active<?php endif; ?>">
                        <a href="<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($category) ?>"><span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) ?></span></a>
                            <?php $subcategories = $category->getChildren() ?>
                            <?php if (count($subcategories) > 0): ?>
                                <ul id="leftnav-tree-<?php echo $category->getId() ?>" class="level1">
                                    <?php foreach($subcategories as $subcategory): ?>
                                        <li class="level1<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($subcategory)): ?> active<?php endif; ?>">
                                            <a href="<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($subcategory) ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml(trim($subcategory->getName(), '- ')) ?></a>
                                                <?php $subsubcategories = $subcategory->getChildren() ?>
                                                <?php if (count($subcategories) > 0): ?>
                                                    <ul id="leftnav-tree-<?php echo $category->getId() ?>" class="level2">
                                                        <?php foreach($subsubcategories as $subsubcategory): ?>
                                                        <li class="level2<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($subsubcategory)): ?> active<?php endif; ?>">
                                                            <a href="<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($subsubcategory) ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml(trim($subsubcategory->getName(), '- ')) ?></a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                                    </ul>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                        </li>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </ul>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

edit: Original code only showed subcatgories for the *currently* viewed category

Comment: Thank you Josh, but can you be more specific? Like where to be replaced with this Mage::helper and getCategoryUrl? I'm a little lost.

Comment: @TheJinStudio No problem, amended my answer for you

Comment: I have tried your first code. It generates the same URL as mine. So still it leads to the same 404 issue. And for the second code, I pasted it to replace my code. Then the categories won't show up. I think I might need to take a look at it before use it. Thank you

Comment: Josh, I am now using your second code coz it works now since I moved all categories under Default Category. Problem is, it only displays one level. But I would like it to display all subcategories. How do I do that? Thank you.

Comment: `getChildren()` is the method you use on a category model to get it's subcategories. Check your subcategories are set up correctly?

Comment: Yahoo! I managed it. Simply deleted the `<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($category)): ?>` and its corresponding `endif`, so all subcategories are displaying now. Thank you!

Comment: @TheJinStudio Oh yes of course! Sorry, that code does that by design but I completely forget about it!!! My mistake, glad you got the code working :)